# Replant to replace soil

Tags: planting, soil-amendment

I bought a little [Zinfin Doll](http://springmeadownursery.com/plant/38870) hydrangea and cleared a patch of some [Annabelles](https://plantaddicts.com/annabelle-hydrangea) that had used the soil for at least five years. (Their flowers unfortunately always grew too heavy for the stalks!)

I didn't get to planting at the end of the day, so while I was out yesterday, a family member planted the Zinfin Doll. But they neglected to put new soil around the roots, not realizing we had a bag.

Which would be better now: To leave it as it is, or to dig it up and risk trauma to put new soil in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take it up again - it was only planted yesterday, it's not like it's had time to settle in or put out new roots, it will still be pot shaped where the roots are,exactly as it was when it went in. You haven't said what this new bag of 'soil' is, but really, it would be better to dig the area over and add some composted manure or good garden compost, then dig a hole and plant, rather than digging a single hole and surrounding the rootball with soil from your bag, if that soil is potting or topsoil.

Comment: Thanks! I've done this now. It was just potting soil in the bag, so I got some compost as well to enrich the surrounding soil.